# Returning string initialized from scalar of volatiles behaves very strange?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to make reverse engineering more difficult with string literals like in the first block of code. I am initializing it as a scalar with volatiles. It is volatile so the compiler won't optimize it and turn it into a plain string literal upon compilation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
static const volatile char a = 'a', b = 'b', c = 'c', d = 'd', e = 'e', f = 'f';
inline const char *_GetString(void) {
    return (const char[]){a, b, c, d, e, f, 0};
}
const char *GetString(void) {
    const char *x = _GetString();
    puts(x);
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts(GetString());
    return 0;
}
```

The preceding does not print `abcdef` twice. However this does:

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char *_GetString(void) {
    return "abcdef";
}
const char *GetString(void) {
    const char *x = _GetString();
    puts(x);
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts(GetString());
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen? How can I return a string from the function in this manner, that does not act odd, but still preserve the function being inline and difficult to reverse engineer?

Comment: "The following does not print abcdef twice."  What *does* it print?

Answer (score 4):

Compound literals, like the one inside of `_GetString` in your first code snippet, have the same lifetime as any variable declared in the same scope.  So when the function returns, it returns a pointer to the first element in the array, i.e. a pointer to a local variable.  This means that when the function returns the pointer value returned is no longer valid, and attempting to use it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The second piece of code works because it returns the address of the first element of a string literal, and the lifetime of strings literals is that of the entire program, so the pointer is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
inline const char *_GetString(void)
{
    return (const char[]){a, b, c, d, e, f, 0};
}
```

creates a local array (with a lifetime limited to the lifetime of its enclosing block, which ends when the execution of this function ends in this case), and then returns its address. That's undefined behavior.

Regarding the obfuscation attempt, if your goal is to store an actual *password* inside the executable, I strongly recommend that you avoid doing so. If your program is able to access a password in its text form, a hacker will be able to do it too; the only thing you should be storing in that case would be a cryptographic hash of the password (after salting it).

Comment: The lifetime is limited to the execution of the function, not its scope. Lifetime is **when** an **object** exists. Scope is **where** an identifier is visible. There is some association between lifetime and scope, but it is possible to access objects outside the scope of their identifiers, such as when the address of an object is passed to a subroutine.

Comment: I believe that the lifetime of automatic variables (and compound literals inside functions) is limited to its enclosing block, not to the enclosing function. This is what @dbush wrote ("lifetime as any variable declared in the same *scope*"). Are you saying that the lifetime of an automatic object inside a nested scope would actually be the entire function?

Comment: The issue is not what the scope is. The problem in this answer is that it incorrectly states the lifetime of the object is limited to a scope. That is wrong. Scope is a set of locations; it is place. Lifetime is a set of times; it is time. Fundamentally, the lifetime of an object cannot be a scope or limited to a scope anymore than a person’s birthday can be New York or limited to New York.

Answer (score 0):

This works, however it does not comply with `inline`. It does return a string, and does not contain any string literals.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const volatile char a = 'a', b = 'b', c = 'c', d = 'd', e = 'e', f = 'f';
const char *GetString(void) {
    static char array[7];
    strcpy(array, (const char[]){a, b, c, d, e, f, 0});
    return array;
}
int main() {
    puts(GetString());
    return 0;
}
```